# Update Angular UI from Express Backend

Tags: angular, express

I am new to MEAN stack. I have a express server (api) which listens at an url and processes incoming data.I wish to develop a front end for this api such that i send and display incoming data , logs and current process step in UI. If the user looks at the UI , he should know the current incoming data, statistics, logs from the UI. Is there any way to send incoming data from express backend and update angular UI .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do that install the node package cors which can be used to listen to request from the cross origin you want. You need this because your angular app runs on a different port by default `4200`. so any request generated from your angular app uses port 4200.

[image]

After that create an angular service to. fetch the data from the API you have created.
It should look like this

[image]

after that, you can fetch the data to the component you want and show it in the component's template.

for more information on angular service read the documentation it has a very good example in it

Comment: Instead of Angular reading the data from express via service, is there any way to push the data from express to angular whenever data is received ?.

Comment: you could use push notifications for that from the express app

Comment: CORS should be used with caution. If you are not developing a public API, then you should strictly avoid using CORS.